# Adding @ModelAttribute results in 400 (Bad Request) in Delete Request

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller

I can submit a delete request fine with the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<Result> deleteTest(@PathVariable String id) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(Result.Success("Hi " + id + "!!!", null), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

However, when I add an `@ModelAttribute` variable, I get 400 (Bad Request) as the http response code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<Result> deleteTest(@PathVariable String id, @ModelAttribute("authUser") User authUser) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(Result.Success("Hi " + id + "!!!", null), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This `@ModelAttribute` is working fine with a put request handler I have in my `@RestController` but not in this delete request.

Here's the `@ModelAttribute` code:

```
@ModelAttribute("authUser")
public User authUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal SpringAuthUser springAuthUser) throws Exception {
    User user = ConstantsHome.userprofileMgr.getUserByUserId(springAuthUser.getUsername(), true, true);
    user.updateRights(null);
    request.getSession().setAttribute(ConstantsHome.USEROBJECT_KEY, user);
    return user;
}
```

Why would adding `@ModelAttribute` cause a delete request to return a 400 (Bad Request) http response?

I'm using spring-web-4.1.4 & spring-security-4.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I digged a little and found that specifying a `@PathVariable` of "id" somehow attaches it to the `@ModelAttribute` variable (as a Long(!) instead of a String as I specified).  I then came across this post that lead me to different ways to resolve the issue :

[Values of @PathVariable and @ModelAttribute overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618895/values-of-pathvariable-and-modelattribute-overlapping).

Ended up with this as a method declaration (replaced "id" with "userId"):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<Result> deleteUser(@PathVariable String userId,
                                         @ModelAttribute("authUser") User authUser) {
    ...
}
```

Hopefully this will help someone else quickly that might run into this issue instead of spending a day trying to figure it out...